How can I as a player handle the NPCs in a campaign stealing the spotlight?
To preface this, I'll start by saying that I've been playing D&D for years! I've been a player in plenty of campaigns, and have ran a couple 5e campaigns of my own. My point is, I have quite a bit of experience with the game.
Now, to the issue at hand.
I have a friend group that currently has two campaigns going. One has been running on three years now, and the DM is fantastic. The second campaign was started a couple months ago by one of the players from the first campaign who wanted to try his hand at being a DM. It was the first time he'd ever ran something, and we all agreed that more D&D was better! We'll call this friend Jasper.
Jasper's campaign has been increasingly difficult to get through, for the sole fact that it seems that he's trying to incorporate our characters into his story rather than building the story around the characters. A recent example would be that he had us fight a monster that was of a considerably higher level than our party (our party was level 3. We were fighting a Catoblepas). It was pretty clear that we weren't meant to win the fight, and so some characters started trying to retreat.
The DM then had an NPC come and kill the catoblepas in one attack. This NPC is a "creature" (his word) that has been stalking the party for several sessions. We have fought it multiple times, and every time it flees or we are otherwise interrupted from killing it. All in all, we walked away from this combat encounter feeling like it was a complete waste of time.
He also has a tendency to make what I'll just call Mary Sue-adjacent NPCs. The current villain of the week is a mysterious bounty hunter who's always wearing a skull-shaped mask. He seems to appear out of nowhere, always manages to find the party, and plays mind games with them. He was apparently hired by the mother of one of the characters to bring said character back home. This character is being roleplayed as having amnesia, so she has no idea why this could be happening.
The idea itself is interesting, but the execution is turning out to be pretty awful. The bounty hunter enjoys monologuing, and making thinly-veiled threats while maintaining this forced air of enigma. Think like Dio from JJBA. He has also shown up multiple times, and Jasper straight-up refuses to allow us to engage him in combat. This character has done nothing to establish himself as a real threat besides murder a few nameless NPCs and talk a whole bunch. It's honestly getting pretty old.
He's also laid out incredibly detailed lore for some other NPCs. Namely, how powerful they are (he once stated that one of these NPCs could deal 480d6 damage with one punch. I asked if he was ever planning on having us fight her. He said no.), how beautiful they are, or a dozen other "cool" things about them. He's constantly sharing things in our group chat or asking us how the party would react to certain situations with his characters, to the point where he'll even hijack conversations about the original long-running campaign to talk more about his world.
I understand being excited about your world and your characters as a DM. Running a campaign IS exciting, and the enthusiasm is great! Not to mention that this is his first campaign, so I'm happy to give him some leeway. But it seems like everything the players want to do is secondary to HIS world and HIS story. I'm starting to dread his sessions.
Would it be better to just quit without an explanation, or maybe discuss the issues with Jasper directly? I'm not sure that he's aware of what he's doing, and I don't want to upset him. It is tricky because of the overlap in the players in both campaigns. Any advice would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Is Japser also an experienced player, or is he pretty new to D&D? Does he have similar "show & tell" behavior for his PC in the other campaign?

@DwayneTheVrock Jasper is an experienced player as well. And he does do similar things in the campaign where he's a player. He plays a monk that's always the wise, rational, stoic one and is always incredibly eager to demonstrate how his character can do things like catch bullets, walk on water, etc. He's easily the strongest member of our party. It's less egregious because that DM handles it well, and keeps everything in check.

Help him improve, or leave if he can't
It's clear that Jesper is committing a litany of godawful rookie DM mistakes. Overshadowing the PCs that should be the stars of the story with overpowered pet DMPCs. Killing player agency by telling you that your characters cannot do the things they want to do with no good reason. Letting opponents get away by DM fiat, just because he does not want them to die. All cardinal sins of bad DMing.
Now, nobody is perfect, and we all gotta learn. If you do not tell him that these things are not making the game fun, he has no way to correct what he is doing. Of course, this is sensitive, nobody likes to be criticized and told what they do sucks. So, let them know best out of game in a 1:1 setting, don't judge, don't call them out for doing it wrong. Use messages that for you, this does not work. That you personally are not enjoying these things, and rather would do something else than play that way. It might also be useful to ask the other players how they feel about it, and if they dislike it as much, they can also let him know. Repetition reinforces. Maybe he is willing to listen and improves.
If not, no D&D is better than bad D&D. In your case, you even do have a great campaign you can continue on in. Let him know this DM style is just not for you, and that you are content with just playing in that other campaign, and drop out of this one. He also is a player in that other campaign if I understand you right, and you don't have any problems with him as a player. So you still can be friends and have fun together, even after dropping out.

I agree with absolutely all of this including the conclusion that no D&D is better than bad D&D. But I think its worth emphasizing that these things are pretty common with new DMs. Talking to him and asking him to change is still the right answer, but I think there's a very good chance of that working and a decent chance that time and experience would fix a lot of this.

Good News (?)
I've got good news for you (I hope).  You've seem to have a rookie GM who has what appears to be some interesting ideas he wants to incorporate into a campaign for you and your fellow players, but who doesn't have the experience needed to properly tweak narrative tropes to a co-operative storytelling situation.  Most (probably all) GMs run into this issue early on.  Especially if they don't start out running pre-written modules.
He's probably used to characterization, pacing, & narrative choices from his favorite media (I'm guessing manga/anime from some of the choices you mention, but I could be totally off base there), and isn't quite aware of how they translate to an RPG setting.  It's an experience issue, and a communication issue.  Tropes have to be adapted to the media they're used in, and narrative techniques don't always work the same way across different media.  Think of how many movies you've seen where there are scenes showing the audience information the characters clearly have no idea is happening.  (Luke has no idea what's happened aboard the Death Star prior to his arrival, but you do, and that sets certain expectations, and clarifies the situation for you.)
Let's take a look at a couple of the scenarios presented, two variants the the 'mysterious frenemy' trope: The Creature and the Bounty Hunter.
The Creature
This is a mysterious beast shown to be 'stalking' the party, but which shows up to help when the party gets in over their head.  It may or may not actually be friendly, but that gets revealed in full over the course of multiple episodes stretched across a season or two.
The Creature could be as simple as your newbie GM realizing he doesn't actually know how to properly balance a combat encounter yet, and wanting to have something in his back pocket to pull the players fat out of the fire if he discovers he's screwed up.  Or, he could have bigger plans.
This one is probably the easiest to deal with, though, because as a mysterious creature it probably isn't tied to a major, player-centric plot point he has in mind.  Have a friendly conversation with the GM, and explain that you don't understand what the point of the Cat-fight, as it felt like it was just a no-win scenario without a purpose.  He may have tried communicating it, but you clearly missed it.  Or, maybe, being used to narrative pacing, he's figuring the reveal of the Creature's nature/purpose ought to be a 'big reveal' moment, when it's probably better to have more openly hinted at in a co-op storytelling scenario like a table-top RPG.
The point to communicate here is that you're confused about the point of the encounter.
The Bounty Hunter
This one is trickier.  After all, it is clearly built to be a PC-centric plot point, and clarifying what's intended there is much more likely to include spoilers the GM won't feel ready to just openly reveal.  The root concern is very similar though.  You (the players) aren't sure how he's expecting you to react to this NPC, but it clearly isn't how you're prepared to react, since he's gone so far as to simply disallow those reactions.
The mysterious bounty hunter sent by person-who-is-ostensibly-an-ally is a common trope, and executed well it can be fun.  He's clearly supposed to remain mysterious until some future, major plot moment.  The problem here seems to be that he's lost the 'mystery' aspect through overuse, while you've been prevented from having any sort of meaningful interaction.  This goes better in narrative media, because both sides know the 'appropriate' interaction at all times, as the interactions are fully scripted.  You don't have a copy of the 'script'.
He's been sent to take the PC to their parents, but he isn't actively doing so.  There's clearly something else at play that you've missed, or your GM hasn't realized ought to be communicated to you in some way.
On this one, make it clear that you like the concept.  It's interesting.  You're just (again) unsure about the point and expected direction this is 'supposed' to take.
You might even, after a quick conversation to make sure he's ready for it to happen, clean up the major concerns the party is dealing with now, and have the party go to the parents to find out what's going on.
A lot of being an experienced GM is recognizing that you're working with the players to tell a story, and trusting them to react in-character appropriately to information even if it includes information the character doesn't know.
The PC has amnesia.  The player doesn't.  The player can (probably) be trusted to have a general idea of whether or not going to see the parent is a good idea or not, and apply that out-of-character knowledge appropriately to the in-character knowledge to further the story in an interesting, meaningful, and appropriate way.  But inexperienced GMs often aren't comfortable sharing like that because they don't want to spoil the plot, and aren't necessarily sure what information can be shared without spoiling the plot.
A short conversation in character might be able to resolve this one.

BH: shows up
PC: "You've been sent to take me home to mom, right?"
BH: "Yes."
PC: "But you haven't tried to do it, yet.  Why not?"
BH: {GM inserts reasoning here.}

TL;DR
In short, this looks like a combination of an eager (good), well-meaning (also good), but inexperienced GM trying to provide an interesting story.  You've run into some rough spots, but having a calm discussion with them to figure out what you've missed, or what might be communicated to help clarify it can probably go a long way toward resolving that.
